# Using R in Python with Rpy2: how to ggplot2?

Tags: r, python-2.7, ggplot2, rpy2

I am trying to use R in Python and I found Rpy2 very interesting. It is powerful and not that difficult to use, however even if I have read the documentation and looked for a similar question, I wasn't able to solve my problem with the ggplot2 library.

Basically I have a dataset with 2 columns, 11 rows and no header and I would like to do a scatter plot using this R code from Python:

```
ggplot(dataset,aes(dataset$V1, dataset$V2))+geom_point()+scale_color_gradient(low="yellow",high="red")+geom_smooth(method='auto')+labs(title = "Features distribution on Scaffolds", x='Scaffolds Length', y='Number of Features')
```

I have tested this code in R (after read.table my file) and it works. Now, this is my python script:

```
import math, datetime
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 as ggplot2

r = robjects.r
df = r("read.table('file_name.txt',sep='\t', header=F)")
gp = ggplot2.ggplot(df, ggplot2.aes(df[0], df[1])) + ggplot2.geom_point() + ggplot2.scale_color_gradient(low="yellow",high="red") + ggplot2.geom_smooth(method='auto') + ggplot2.labs(title = "Features distribution on Scaffolds", x='Scaffolds Length', y='Number of Features')
gp.plot()
```

If i run this Python code, it gives me two errors. The first is:

```
gp = ggplot2.ggplot(df, ggplot2.aes(df[0], df[1]))
TypeError: new() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

and the second is:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scale_color_gradient'
```

Can someone help me to understand where I'm wrong please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps you need to associate a dataframe column to the colour of the scatter
points so that the `scale_colour_gradient` can be associated to that column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects.packages as packages
import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 as ggplot2
import rpy2.robjects as ro
R = ro.r
datasets = packages.importr('datasets')
mtcars = packages.data(datasets).fetch('mtcars')['mtcars']
gp = ggplot2.ggplot(mtcars)
pp = (gp 
      + ggplot2.aes_string(x='wt', y='mpg')
      + ggplot2.geom_point(ggplot2.aes_string(colour='qsec'))
      + ggplot2.scale_colour_gradient(low="yellow", high="red") 
      + ggplot2.geom_smooth(method='auto') 
      + ggplot2.labs(title="mtcars", x='wt', y='mpg'))

pp.plot()
R("dev.copy(png,'/tmp/out.png')")
```

[image]

---

The error

```
gp = ggplot2.ggplot(df, ggplot2.aes(df[0], df[1]))
TypeError: new() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

occurred because `ggplot2.ggplot` takes only 1 argument, the dataframe:

```
gp = ggplot2.ggplot(df)
```

You can then add the aesthetics mapping to `gp`:

```
gp + ggplot2.aes_string(x='0', y='1')
```

where `'0'` and `'1'` are column names of `df`. Per the [examples in the docs](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.4/html/graphics.html#package-ggplot2), I've used `aes_string` here instead of `aes`.

---

The second error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scale_color_gradient'
```

occurred because ggplot2 uses the British spelling of color: `scale_colour_gradient`:

Comment: I have changed my code following your tips and it works very well! Thank you very much for your help, hope I reach level 15 soon to up-vote your comment. Thank you again :)

Comment: The American spelling will be added shortly. Thanks for pointing that out @unutbu

Comment: When I tried this in Colab, it just outputs 

IntVector with 1 elements.
5 

instead of the plot. How to fix it?