# Comparing Plumbr to other options for making a chart with R in a Python script

Tags: python, r, ggplot2

I plan on making a chart with ggplot in a python script. These are details about the project:

- I have a script that runs on a remote machine and I can install anything within reason on the machine
- The script runs in python and has data that I want to visualize stored as a dictionary
- The script runs daily and the data always has the same structure

I think my best bet is to do this...

- Write an R script that takes the data and creates the ggplot visualization
- Use [plumbr](https://www.rplumber.io/) to create a rest API for my script
- Send a call to the rest API and get a PNG of my plot in return

I'm also familiar with [ggpy](https://github.com/yhat/ggpy) by yhat and I'm even wondering if I can install R on the machine and just send code directly to the machine to process it without having RStudio.

Would plumbr be a recommended and secure implementation?

This is a reproducible example-

```
my_data = [{"Chicago": "30"} {"New York": "50"}], [{"Cincinatti": "70"}, {"Green Bay": "95"}] 

**{this is the part that's missing}**

library(ggplot)
my_data %>% ggplot(aes(city_name, value)) + geom_col()

png("my_bar_chart.png", my_data)
```

Comment: This looks awesome! I'm hesitant only because I don't want to send my data to their server

Comment: Why do you need a REST API? You can just call R directly from Python with rpy2: https://rpy2.github.io/

Comment: Can I use this to access libraries like `tidyverse` and `ggplot`?

Comment: @Cauder: Yes, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152395/using-r-in-python-with-rpy2-how-to-ggplot2.

Comment: I'd recommend the rpy2 option here.

Comment: Great! Can you please write this as an answer so I can mark it accepted?

Comment: @HongOoi, do you want to post it as an answer as you were the first to mention rpy2? Otherwise i would quote and reference the mentioned post.

Comment: @TonioLiebrand go ahead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, most of your question should be answered here: [Using R in Python with Rpy2: how to ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152395/using-r-in-python-with-rpy2-how-to-ggplot2).

You can load ggplot with:

```
import rpy2.robjects.packages as packages
import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 as ggp2
```

assuming of course you have ggplot2 + dependencies available.

Then you can almost use R syntax, except that you put `ggp2.` in front of every command.

E.g: the Python equivilant of `ggplot(mtcars)` would be `ggp2.ggplot(mtcars)`.

**Your example:** (not tested)

```
my_data = [{"Chicago": "30"} {"New York": "50"}], [{"Cincinatti": "70"}, {"Green Bay": "95"}] 

import rpy2.robjects.packages as packages
import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggp2 as ggp2

plot = ggp2.ggplot(my_data) + 
  ggp2.aes(city_name, value)) + 
  ggp2.geom_col()

plot.plot()

R("dev.copy(png, 'my_data.png')")
```

Comment: This is literally incredible