# R ggplot2 in Python noyebooks in Colab

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I've tried to run presentation "POLYGLOT DATA ANALYSIS VISUALLY DEMONSTRATED WITH PYTHON AND R" [Python notebook, running R code dated 2016 from github repo](https://github.com/lgautier/jpd-pdapr-slides) in Colab

but it says ***lazyeval*** package is absent.

When I tried to install it as foloows

```
%%R
install.packages("lazyeval")
```

it outputs like

> R[write to console]: Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> R[write to console]: trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lazyeval_0.2.2.tar.gz'
>
> R[write to console]: Content type 'application/x-gzip'
> R[write to console]:  length 83482 bytes (81 KB)
>
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]: =
> R[write to console]:
>
> R[write to console]: downloaded 81 KB
>
> R[write to console]:
>
> R[write to console]:
> R[write to console]: The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘/tmp/Rtmp6hM38b/downloaded_packages’
> R[write to console]:
> R[write to console]:

but no plots are being displayed, with output like full html page inside output cell like this (copy|pasted cell contents)

```
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><span style="color: rgb(33, 33, 33); font-family: Roboto, Noto, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial;">GGPlot with 9 elements.</span><span style="color: rgb(33, 33, 33); font-family: Roboto, Noto, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; display: inline !important; float: none;"></span>

data | R/rpy2 DataFrame (6161 x 8)Request.IDStatusAction.Type...AddressPlatformSubmitted.By'REQ194189''Closed''Repair P......'Concord ...'''bsmyth''REQ194190''Closed''Repair P...'Sunset R...'''bsmyth''REQ194191''Closed''Repair P...'Blanchar...'''bsmyth''REQ194192''Closed''Repair P...'Rindge A...'''bsmyth'..................'REQ545410''Assigned''Repair P...'''iOS''web-serv...'REQ545521''Assigned''Repair P...'''''web-serv...'REQ545560''Assigned''Repair P...'''Android''web-serv...'REQ545621''Assigned''Repair P...'''''web-serv... | Request.ID | Status | Action.Type | ... | Address | Platform | Submitted.By | 'REQ194189' | 'Closed' | 'Repair P... | ... | 'Concord ... | '' | 'bsmyth' | 'REQ194190' | 'Closed' | 'Repair P... |   | 'Sunset R... | '' | 'bsmyth' | 'REQ194191' | 'Closed' | 'Repair P... |   | 'Blanchar... | '' | 'bsmyth' | 'REQ194192' | 'Closed' | 'Repair P... |   | 'Rindge A... | '' | 'bsmyth' | ... | ... | ... |   | ... | ... | ... | 'REQ545410' | 'Assigned' | 'Repair P... |   | '' | 'iOS' | 'web-serv... | 'REQ545521' | 'Assigned' | 'Repair P... |   | '' | '' | 'web-serv... | 'REQ545560' | 'Assigned' | 'Repair P... |   | '' | 'Android' | 'web-serv... | 'REQ545621' | 'Assigned' | 'Repair P... |   | '' | '' | 'web-serv...
-- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | --

'REQ194189' | 'Closed' | 'Repair P... | ... | 'Concord ... | '' | 'bsmyth'
'REQ194190' | 'Closed' | 'Repair P... |   | 'Sunset R... | '' | 'bsmyth'
'REQ194191' | 'Closed' | 'Repair P... |   | 'Blanchar... | '' | 'bsmyth'
'REQ194192' | 'Closed' | 'Repair P... |   | 'Rindge A... | '' | 'bsmyth'
... | ... | ... |   | ... | ... | ...
'REQ545410' | 'Assigned' | 'Repair P... |   | '' | 'iOS' | 'web-serv...
'REQ545521' | 'Assigned' | 'Repair P... |   | '' | '' | 'web-serv...
'REQ545560' | 'Assigned' | 'Repair P... |   | '' | 'Android' | 'web-serv...
'REQ545621' | 'Assigned' | 'Repair P... |   | '' | '' | 'web-serv...
ListVector with 1 elements.[no name][RTYPES.ENVSXP] | [RTYPES.ENVSXP]
[RTYPES.ENVSXP]
add: function clone: function find: function get_scales: function has_scale: function input: function n: function non_position_scales: function scales: list super:
...
compute_layout: function draw_back: function draw_front: function draw_labels: function draw_panels: function finish_data: function init_scales: function map_data: function params: list setup_data: function setup_params: function shrink: TRUE train_scales: function vars: function super:
 
ListVector with 3 elements.x[RTYPES.STRSXP]y[RTYPES.STRSXP]weight[RTYPES.STRSXP] | [RTYPES.STRSXP] | [RTYPES.STRSXP] | [RTYPES.STRSXP]
[RTYPES.STRSXP]
[RTYPES.STRSXP]
[RTYPES.STRSXP]

<!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, the presentaion project seems to not been able to add an issue.

There is a post at [SO Using R in Python with Rpy2: how to ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152395/using-r-in-python-with-rpy2-how-to-ggplot2) with code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects.packages as packages
import rpy2.robjects.lib.ggplot2 as ggplot2
import rpy2.robjects as ro
R = ro.r
datasets = packages.importr('datasets')
mtcars = packages.data(datasets).fetch('mtcars')['mtcars']
gp = ggplot2.ggplot(mtcars)
pp = (gp 
      + ggplot2.aes_string(x='wt', y='mpg')
      + ggplot2.geom_point(ggplot2.aes_string(colour='qsec'))
      + ggplot2.scale_colour_gradient(low="yellow", high="red") 
      + ggplot2.geom_smooth(method='auto') 
      + ggplot2.labs(title="mtcars", x='wt', y='mpg'))

pp.plot()
R("dev.copy(png,'/tmp/out.png')")
```

But in Colab it just outputs

> R[write to console]: `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'

> IntVector with 1 elements.
> 5

What is the proper way to use R ggplot2 code in Python notebooks in Colab and how the notebook can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

That presentation is from 6 years ago. It should run with Python and R versions used at the time (along with their respective packages, also with version from that time).

Otherwise some of the content made it to the rpy2 documentation or other more recent write-ups.

- rpy2 in notebooks: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.4.x/html/generated_rst/notebooks.html
- about mixing R into Python, and more about notebooks: https://medium.com/@lgautier/rpy2-is-turning-13-47b2c2689095
- ggplot2: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.4.x/html/graphics.html#package-ggplot2
- dplyr: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.4.x/html/lib_dplyr.html#dplyr